# Why is a parallel stream slower than a sequential stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have two functions solving the same problem.
The first uses a sequential stream, and the second uses a parallel stream.

```
public static int digitalRoot(int n) {
    int sum = String.valueOf(n).chars().map(i -> Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf((char) i))).sum();
    if (sum >= 10) {
        return digitalRoot(sum);
    } else {
        return sum;
    }
}

public static int digitalRootParallel(int n) {
    int sum = String.valueOf(n).chars().parallel().
            map(i -> Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf((char) i))).sum();
    if (sum >= 10) {
        return digitalRootParallel(sum);
    } else {
        return sum;
    }
}
```

I executed these functions once. 
The parallel function *digitalRootParallel()* was faster (5 ms) than the sequential (32 ms) *digitalRoot()*.

But when I executed each of them in a loop of 1.000.000, the sequential (117 ms) was faster than the parallel (1124 ms).

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        sum = digitalRoot(n);
    }
```

Why is the loop with the parallel stream slower?

Answer (score 1):

All I can share is my surprise that you ever measured anything but a slowdown for the parallel version. You give Fork/Join almost no work to do: just to parse and sum up to ten digits. F/J will probably decide it's not even worth splitting it and will execute the whole computation on a single thread, but the overhead involved in this will stifle performance.

If you want to see any benefit of parallelization, then make sure that you have at least half a second's worth of sequential computation and that it is easily splittable into subtasks.

Comment: Actually, F/J will not decide that’s not worth splitting it, as it doesn’t have the necessary knowledge to make such a decision. I tested it and it does use multiple threads, of course, not to any benefit. I added some interesting details about the implementation to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28476336/2711488) (not that it matters for this simple operation …)

Comment: It will actually do something even worse than decide not to split: it will "split" everything into a single batch, and again employ a single thread to do all the computation. And it will keep doing that for sizes up to 1024. I've already spent time banging my head against this splitting policy :)

Comment: I am deriving my conclusion from looking at `Spliterators.IntIteratorSpliterator#trySplit()`. That method uses the hardcoded `BATCH_UNIT` constant as the starting batch size. The constant is `1 << 10`.

Comment: Once the stream has an array, it can be split again by using indices into that array w/o copying. On my machine (4 cores,1.8.0_40) it did sub-array splitting but it also started with a batch size of two, increasing it for each new batch. 1024 would be the starting batch size if the estimated size is bigger than 1024. I don’t know how other implementations look like, but here `Spliterators$IntIteratorSpliterator.trySplit` contains `long s = est; if (s > 1 && i.hasNext()) { int n = batch + BATCH_UNIT; if (n > s) n = (int) s;` clearly capping `n` to `est`, which is the estimated (remaining) size.

Comment: Doubtless the batch size cannot exceed total size---that's what I said: up to total size of 1024, a single batch will be split off the initial spliterator. But you are right that this batch, an array, supports splitting down to single elements; this is where I took Paul Sandoz's word for it, who said that the runtime will not decide to further split the array. When testing with object-based streams, further splitting did indeed not occur.

Comment: By the way, the first thing I did was adding a `System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());` to the lambda expressions which gave me more insight about the parallel execution than dry-looking at the code. The next step was making a break point at the lambda expression and look at the calling `Spliterator`’s actual arrays. Though I was a bit misguided as I thought that it doesn’t know the exact size as `PrimitiveIterator` doesn’t provide that but `Spliterators.spliterator(…)` gets the size as parameter… So I saw rather small batches but of course, these were that small due to the small sources.

Comment: I think that the difference between this case and my previous work was that I had `est == Long.MAX_VALUE`, which is why F/J always preferred reading more batches instead of splitting existing batches into smaller ones. When `est` is finite and starts approaching zero before at least `availableProcessors()` subtasks have been created, F/J then probably decides to dissect the existing batch, no matter how small.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your code is … a bit complicated. Instead of

```
String.valueOf(n).chars().map(i -> Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf((char) i))).sum();
```

you could write

```
String.valueOf(n).chars().map(i -> i-'0').sum();
```

However, even with your original code the operation is so simple that the HotSpot optimizer can transform it to something so short that it executes faster than any starting of a new thread or synchronizing will be.

This applies especially to your benchmark where you perform the operation multiple times without actually using its result. In a pure sequential context, an optimizer can recognize that the result is not used and elide the entire operation if it doesn’t have any side effects. In contrast, a parallel execution or, more abstract, code communicating with other threads has side-effects.

Therefore, the optimizer can’t do the same to operations spanning multiple threads. Nor can the `Stream` implementation recognize the simplicity of the operation. If you request a parallel execution, the `Stream` implementation will respect it, assuming you know what you are doing.

---

Additional remarks:

An interesting property of the *current* implementation of `String.chars()` is that it creates a `PrimitiveIterator.OfInt` that will be wrapped in a `Spliterator.OfInt`, rather than implementing `Spliterator.OfInt` directy. This implies that there is no direct splitting capability as `PrimitiveIterator.OfInt` doesn’t provide that. Instead, the splitting will be performed by iterating over one or more elements, copying them the into an array and provide this array for being processed by a different thread.

But iterating and copying into a temporary array is likely to take more time than the actual operation in a sequential execution.

These poor splitting capabilities are a [known issue](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8071477) that will be addressed in Java 9. But still, your operation is unlikely to benefit from parallel execution.